# Perl: Cross-references in nested datastructures?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

Is there a clean way to, at declaration time, make a stored hash value point to another value in the same datastructure?

For example, say I have a datastructure for command callbacks:

```
my %commands = (
    'a' => {
             'init' => sub { return "common initializer"; },
             'run'  => sub { return "run a"; }
           },
    'b' => {
             'init' => sub { return "init b"; },
             'run'  => sub { return "run b"; }
           },
    'c' => {
             'init' => sub { return "common initializer"; },
             'run'  => sub { return "run c"; }
           }
);
```

I know this could be rewritten as:

```
sub common_initializer() { return "common initializer"; }

my %commands = (
    'a' => {
             'init' => \&common_initializer,
             'run'  => sub { return "run a"; }
           },
    'b' => {
             'init' => sub { return "init b"; },
             'run'  => sub { return "run b"; }
           },
    'c' => {
             'init' => \&common_initializer,
             'run'  => sub { return "run c"; }
           }
);
```

This works but the subroutines are no longer all anonymous.  Double-initialization is another option:

```
sub get_commands($;$) {
    my ($_commands, $pass) = @_;
    %$_commands = (
        'a' => {
                 'init' => sub { return "common initializer"; },
                 'run'  => sub { return "run a"; }
               },
        'b' => {
                 'init' => sub { return "init b"; },
                 'run'  => sub { return "run b"; }
               },
        'c' => {
                 'init' => $$_commands{'a'}{'init'},
                 'run'  => sub { return "run c"; }
               }
    );
    get_commands($_commands, 1) unless (defined $pass);
}

my %commands;
get_commands(\%commands);
```

This works but it's rather kludgy and expensive.  I'm using subroutines in the example above but I'd like this to work for any datatype.  Is there a cleaner way to do this in Perl?

Comment: Solutions of the form `my %commands = ...;` won't work. You can't reference a data structure you haven't created yet. That's why your solutions either do something before or after that.

Comment: Re "*This works but the subroutines are no longer all anonymous*",  There was no reason to make it named sub. `my $common_initializer = sub { return "common initializer"; };` would have worked just as well.

Comment: I really don't see the problem you have with the second snippet (with or without the modification from the previous comment.)

Comment: @ikegami Yea, I know.  I'm hoping there's some obscure syntax that I haven't encountered that could be leveraged to do this.  WRT your latter comments, that method drops things (`$common_initializer` or `&common_initializer`) into the namespace.

Comment: Re "*I'm hoping there's some obscure syntax*", What part of "You can't reference a data structure you haven't created yet" has anything to do with syntax?

Comment: Re "*that method drops things ($common_initializer or &common_initializer) into the namespace*", So add curlies. You're already ok with creating a sub, so this claim is rather ludicrous.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not terribly happy with either of the solutions I gave.  Just looking for a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I see that you are using [prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes) on your subroutines. You should be aware that prototypes in Perl are optional, and they do not do what most people think they do. In most cases, you can just skip them, and your code will be improved.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a clean way to, at declaration time, make a stored hash value point to another value in the same datastructure?

Impossible, by definition. You can't look up a value in the hash before you actually assign it to the hash. As such, solutions of the form `my %h = ...;` can't possibly work.

If you want to avoid duplication, you have two options:

```perl
my $common_val = ...;

my %h = ( a => $common_val, b => $common_val );
```

```perl
my %h = ( a => ..., b => undef );

$h{b} = $h{a};
```

(The first is best because it gives a name to the common thing.)

---

What I would probably do instead is use classes or objects. Inheritance and composition (e.g. roles) provide convenient means of sharing code between classes.

Classes:

```perl
my %commands = (
   a => ClassA,
   b => ClassB,
);
```

Objects:

```perl
my %commands = (
   a => ClassA->new(),
   b => ClassB->new(),
);
```

Either way, the caller would look like this:

```perl
$commands{$id}->init();
```

Taking it one step further, you could get rid of `%commands` entirely by naming the classes `Command::a`, `Command::b`, etc. Then all you'd need is

```perl
( "Command::" . $id )->init();
```

You're effectively using plugins at this point. There are modules that might make using a plugin even more shiny.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that using a named subroutine might be the best option. E.g.:

```
sub foo { return "foo" }

my %commands ( "a" => { 'init' => \&foo } );
```

It is easily repeatable, contained and even allows you to add arguments dynamically.

But you can also use a lookup-table:

```
my %commands ( "a" => {
        'init' => "foo",
        'run'  => "foo"
    });
my %run  = ( "foo" => sub { return "run foo" });
my %init = ( "foo" => sub { return "init foo" });

print "The run for 'a' is: " . $run{ $commands{a}{run} }->() . "\n";
```

This looks a bit more complicated to me, but it would work for any datatype, as you requested.

I see that you are using [prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes), e.g. `sub foo($;$)`. You should be aware that these are optional, and they do not do what most people think. Most often you can skip these, and your code will be improved. Read the documentation.

Comment: I use prototypes just to get some basic runtime parameter count checks.  They also provide a handy way to see what's required and what's optional (which I what I used it for in my example).

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I'll mull it over a bit before commenting more.  (I'm a bit distracted investigating using trampolines for this right now; seems quite promising but only works for `sub`s.)

Comment: @AlexHajnal You can add clarity with a comment, and you can count parameters, with an explicit check `my $count = @_`. While you may know what they mean, they may be very confusing to others. And like I said, they do not do what most people think. But in the end, it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Answering my own question but I'm still open to other solutions.*

One alternate approach I've come up with is to mark cross-references with specially-formatted strings.  At runtime the datastructure is traversed and any such strings are replaced with pointers to the values they name.

This is lighter-weight than the double-initialization method I mentioned in my question.  It also has the advantage of keeping everything referenced in the datastructure within the datastructure (i.e. subroutines are all inline).  I'm using subroutine references in the example below but this technique can be adapted for use with arbitrary datatypes (i.e. by removing the sanity check).

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub ALIAS($$@);
sub COOK(\%);

my %h = (
         'a' => {
                  'init' => sub { return "common initializer\n"; },
                  'run'  => sub { return "common run\n"; },
                },
         'b' => { 
                  'init' => sub { return "init b\n"; },
                  'run'  => "ALIAS {'a'}{'run'}"
                },
         'c' => {
            ALIAS 'init' => '{a}{"init"}',
                  'run'  => sub { return "run c\n"; },
                },
);

COOK(%h);

print "Init a: " . &{$h{'a'}{'init'}}();
print "Init b: " . &{$h{'b'}{'init'}}();
print "Init c: " . &{$h{'c'}{'init'}}();

print "Run a:  " . &{$h{'a'}{'run'}}();
print "Run b:  " . &{$h{'b'}{'run'}}();
print "Run c:  " . &{$h{'c'}{'run'}}();


# Replaces function aliases with references to the pointed to functions.
#
# Alias format is 'ALIAS {COMMAND}{FUNCTION}' where COMMAND and FUNCTION are
# the top-level and second-level keys in the passed datastructure.  Both 
# COMMAND and FUNCTION can optionally be quoted.  See also ALIAS(...) for 
# some syntatic sugar.
#
# IN: %commands -> Hash containing command descriptors (passed by reference)
sub COOK(\%) {
    my ($_commands) = @_;
    
    # Loop through commands...
    foreach my $command ( keys %$_commands ) {
        
        # Loop through functions...
        foreach my $function ( keys %{$$_commands{$command}} ) {
            
            # Only consider strings
            next if ( ref $$_commands{$command}{$function} );
            
            # Does the string look like an alias?
            if ( $$_commands{$command}{$function} 
                 =~ /^ALIAS\s+
                      \{
                         (
                           (?: [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ ) | 
                           (?:'[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+') | 
                           (?:"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+") 
                         )
                      \}
                      \{
                         (
                           (?: [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ ) | 
                           (?:'[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+') | 
                           (?:"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+")  
                         )
                      \}
                     $/x ) {
                
                # Matched, find where it points to
                my ($link_to_command, $link_to_function) = ($1, $2);
                $link_to_command  =~ s/['"]//g;
                $link_to_function =~ s/['"]//g;
                
                # Sanity check
                unless (ref $$_commands{$link_to_command}{$link_to_function} eq 'CODE') {
                    die "In COOK(...), {$command}{$function} points to " .
                        "{$link_to_command}{$link_to_function} " .
                        "which is not a subroutine reference";
                }
                
                # Replace string with reference to pointed-to function
                $$_commands{$command}{$function} 
                    = $$_commands{$link_to_command}{$link_to_function};
            } # END - Alias handler
        } # END - Functions loop
    } # END - Commands loop
} # END - COOK(...)


# Function providing syntatic sugar to let one write:
#   ALIAS 'key' => "{command}{function}"
#
# instead of:
#   'key' => "ALIAS {command}{function}"
#
# This makes aliased functions more visible and makes it easier to write an 
# appropriate code syntax highlighting pattern.
#
# See also COOK(...)
sub ALIAS($$@) {
    my ($key, $alias, @rest) = @_;
    return $key, "ALIAS $alias", @rest;
}
```

When run, this outputs:

```
Init a: common initializer
Init b: init b
Init c: common initializer
Run a:  common run
Run b:  common run
Run c:  run c
```

Comment: I ended up using the solution that I devised pretty much verbatim.  End result [is here](https://github.com/Alex-Kent/checksum_tools).